# How do I remove starting comma from a hashtag converted string - ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was trying to convert a single string with hashtags to a string separated by commas.
How do I remove the starting comma `,` in the result. Could anyone please help.

Here's what I tried so far.

```js
const tags = '#chat #application #blog #guide #create #ionic #gon'

console.log(
  tags
  .split('#')
  .map(val => val.trim())
  .join(',')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about filtering a collection before `Array#map`?

> [**`filter(Boolean)`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is equavalent to `filter(val => Boolean(val))`. As `""` is a `falsey` value, it will be false hence eliminated from array.

```js
const tags = '#chat #application #blog #guide #create #ionic #gon'

console.log(
  tags
  .split('#')
  .filter(Boolean)
  .map(val => val.trim())
  .join(',')
);
```

Comment: Just curious, how did it took out the empty element in this case by using `filter` ?

Comment: @Pavan filter(Boolean) is the same as filter( function(x) { return Boolean(x); }). Empty string is a false value in javascript so it will filter out empty string.

Comment: @Pavan - `filter(Boolean)` is equavalent to `filter(val=>Boolean(val))`. As `""` is a falsey value, it will be false hence eliminated from array.

Comment: That explains. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter empty string so that there will be no ',' for the first empty string.

```
console.log(
tags
.split('#')
.filter((val) => val != '')
.map(val => val.trim())
.join(',')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove first element from `split` array by `slice(1)`

```js
const tags = '#chat #application #blog #guide #create #ionic #gon'

console.log(
  tags
  .split('#').slice(1).map(val => val.trim())
  .join(',')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) like in the following snippet:

```js
const tags = '#chat #application #blog #guide #create #ionic #gon'

console.log(
  tags
  .split('#')
  .map(val => val.trim())
  .join(',')
  .substring(1, tags.length)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add a .filter() to delete the empty spaces after the .split()

```js
const tags = '#chat #application #blog #guide #create #ionic #gon'

console.log(
  tags
     .split("#")
     .filter(val => val)
     .map(val => val.trim())
     .join(", ")
);
```